# Inconsistent x-axis with ggplot facets using POSIXct x variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, posixct

I have a series of related graphs I would like to present as facets but the x-axis values will not align even though actual x values are identical for both facets.

As 2 facets, R produces this:

[image: X values unaligned]

When I use the same code with separately using dataframes with only one nodenum, each graph appears as expected with identical x-axis ranges

[image: One facet alone]

[image: Second facet alone]

If I use scales="free_x" then the two facets look fine, but their X axes are labeled differently (offset by 12 hours)

[image: facets properly aligned but x axes reflect improper 12-hour offsets]

Here is R code for all graphs.  The only difference between the first 3 examples were subsetting the dataframes to include both or only one of the nodenum values used for selecting the facet.  The last used the commented-out scales="free_x argument

```
nn00$pikaday <- "2018-09-12"  # One explicit date
 nn01<-subset(nn00,nn00$Day_LOC == pikaday )
# Using or omitting tz= in the next line has no effect on graphs
ToD<-as.POSIXct(nn01$Xint_UTC,tz=Local_TZ)  # Time-Of Day
g3<-ggplot(nn01,aes(ToD)) + geom_point(aes(y=v.temp.m04),color="blue") +
  labs(y="Temps")
# g3 + facet_wrap(~ nodenum,nrow=2,scales="free_x") +
 g3 + facet_wrap(~ nodenum,nrow=2) +
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("6 hours"),
                   labels = date_format("%H:%M")) +
  theme(panel.background =element_rect(fill="white"))
```

How can I get all the facets to repeat the same basic ranges and formats?

Here are head and tail values which seem unremarkable.

```
> head(nn01[,c(55,5,3,16)])
     nodenum    Day_LOC            Xint_LOC v.temp.m04
5148     08D 2018-09-11 2018-09-11 19:00:00      25.10
5150     04D 2018-09-11 2018-09-11 19:00:00      25.30
5203     08D 2018-09-11 2018-09-11 19:30:00      24.80
5205     04D 2018-09-11 2018-09-11 19:30:00      25.29
5258     08D 2018-09-11 2018-09-11 20:00:00      24.30
5260     04D 2018-09-11 2018-09-11 20:00:00      24.90
> tail(nn01[,c(55,5,3,16)])
     nodenum    Day_LOC            Xint_LOC v.temp.m04
7613     08D 2018-09-12 2018-09-12 17:30:00      28.60
7615     04D 2018-09-12 2018-09-12 17:30:00      27.00
7663     08D 2018-09-12 2018-09-12 18:00:00      27.50
7665     04D 2018-09-12 2018-09-12 18:00:00      27.40
7712     08D 2018-09-12 2018-09-12 18:30:00      27.70
7714     04D 2018-09-12 2018-09-12 18:30:00      26.61
```

Comment: Can you share your data using `dput`?

Comment: Either provide data to support the plots (such as @markus' suggestion to use something like `dput(x)`), or provide plots that use the data you've provided. Or both. But something more, please. (I suspect that you need to provide more data, since there appear to be nuances that would be lost using just `head`/`tail`.)